# How to use puppet APT module to install varnish server

Tags: puppet, varnish

I am trying to implement the latest version of varnish server using Puppet with APT module, however, I am getting some errors. I need to use "--force-yes". How do I go about doing that. Can anyone suggest me what I maybe doing wrong or point me to an example. Thanks

[Here's what I'm trying to do](https://www.varnish-cache.org/installation/ubuntu)

This is what I have done so far.

```
class profile::varnish {
    notify{'Provisioning varnish server': }

    include apt

    apt::key {'apt-key':
        id => 'E98C6BBBA1CBC5C3EB2DF21C60E7C096C4DEFFEB',
        source => 'https://repo.varnish-cache.org/GPG-key.txt'
    }

    apt::source {'varnish':
        location => 'https://repo.varnish-cache.org/ubuntu/',
        release => 'trusty',
        repos => 'varnish-4.1',
        require => Apt::Key['apt-key']
    }

    package {'varnish':
        ensure => installed,
        require => Apt::Source['varnish']
    }
}
```

Here's the error, I am getting with Puppet agent.

```
Error: Execution of '/usr/bin/apt-get -q -y -o DPkg::Options::=--force-confold install varnish' returned 100: Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
The following extra packages will be installed:
  gcc gcc-4.8 libasan0 libatomic1 libc-dev-bin libc6-dev libgcc-4.8-dev
  libitm1 libjemalloc1 libquadmath0 libtsan0 libvarnishapi1 linux-libc-dev
  manpages-dev
Suggested packages:
  gcc-multilib make autoconf automake1.9 libtool flex bison gdb gcc-doc
  gcc-4.8-multilib gcc-4.8-doc gcc-4.8-locales libgcc1-dbg libgomp1-dbg
  libitm1-dbg libatomic1-dbg libasan0-dbg libtsan0-dbg libquadmath0-dbg
  glibc-doc varnish-doc
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  gcc gcc-4.8 libasan0 libatomic1 libc-dev-bin libc6-dev libgcc-4.8-dev
  libitm1 libjemalloc1 libquadmath0 libtsan0 libvarnishapi1 linux-libc-dev
  manpages-dev varnish
0 upgraded, 15 newly installed, 0 to remove and 2 not upgraded.
Need to get 585 kB/12.3 MB of archives.
After this operation, 43.4 MB of additional disk space will be used.
WARNING: The following packages cannot be authenticated!
  libvarnishapi1 varnish
E: There are problems and -y was used without --force-yes

Error: /Stage[main]/Profile::Varnish/Package[varnish]/ensure: change from absent to present failed: Execution of '/usr/bin/apt-get -q -y -o DPkg::Options::=--force-confold install varnish' returned 100: Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
The following extra packages will be installed:
  gcc gcc-4.8 libasan0 libatomic1 libc-dev-bin libc6-dev libgcc-4.8-dev
  libitm1 libjemalloc1 libquadmath0 libtsan0 libvarnishapi1 linux-libc-dev
  manpages-dev
Suggested packages:
  gcc-multilib make autoconf automake1.9 libtool flex bison gdb gcc-doc
  gcc-4.8-multilib gcc-4.8-doc gcc-4.8-locales libgcc1-dbg libgomp1-dbg
  libitm1-dbg libatomic1-dbg libasan0-dbg libtsan0-dbg libquadmath0-dbg
  glibc-doc varnish-doc
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  gcc gcc-4.8 libasan0 libatomic1 libc-dev-bin libc6-dev libgcc-4.8-dev
  libitm1 libjemalloc1 libquadmath0 libtsan0 libvarnishapi1 linux-libc-dev
  manpages-dev varnish
0 upgraded, 15 newly installed, 0 to remove and 2 not upgraded.
Need to get 585 kB/12.3 MB of archives.
After this operation, 43.4 MB of additional disk space will be used.
WARNING: The following packages cannot be authenticated!
  libvarnishapi1 varnish
E: There are problems and -y was used without --force-yes
```

**Update:**
Those of you who are wondering how I have managed to get the apt::key ID, I have used the following command

```
gpg --with-fingerprint your-gpg-key.txt
```

You will want the **key fingerprint** output, without the spaces. I thought I share this with you, because it took me awhile to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if it is the right approach, however, I have managed to solve this problem by adding the following lines in the profile::varnish class.

```
exec { 'apt-update':
  command => "/usr/bin/apt-get update",
  logoutput => "on_failure",
  path => "/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/sbin",
}

exec { 'apt-upgrade':
  command => "/usr/bin/apt-get --quiet --yes --fix-broken upgrade",
  logoutput => "on_failure",
  path => "/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/sbin",
  require => Exec['apt-update'],
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add gpg keys with the apt module too https://forge.puppetlabs.com/puppetlabs/apt#add-gpg-keys

```
apt::key { 'puppetlabs':
  id      => '47B320EB4C7C375AA9DAE1A01054B7A24BD6EC30',
  server  => 'pgp.mit.edu',
  options => 'http-proxy="http://proxyuser:proxypass@example.org:3128"',
}
```